# About copy and paste content and formatting

Tags: css

when I copy my content from my WordPad and paste it into Wordpress Visual editor it shows line break on post display on the browser whenever a line is started in visual editor

Comment: Can't understand your question. But are you missing [this](https://blogs.ces.uwex.edu/wordpress/posts-2/copy-and-paste-from-word/)?

Answer (score 0):

Paste the content in the visual mode and adjust the line spacing and save it.Avoid the spacing between the lines.

if  you are pasting the content in editor mode use the html tags properly,avoid the like breaks and spacing between lines ,
use like these

```
<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/> consectetur adipiscing elit</h4>
<p>Lorem iscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuadipiscingelitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
<p>consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,color sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elitLoreconsectetur adipiscing elit</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you copy and paste content from Word into a page, it can cause all sorts of formatting issues and even cause the text to be "broken".

To solve this open your post/page and click on visual. On Visual you can see the Toolbar Toggle, And then click the Paste as text button. Click OK and return to the Editing Post/Page screen. You will now see that the Paste as Text button has a square border around it, which indicates it is now turned on. Using CTRL+V, paste the Word content into the Visual editor and you will see that the content will appear without formatting. To turn this feature off, simply click on the Paste as Text button, which will toggle the button back to the off position.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]